# PostgreSQL: options for large table

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a project dealing with genomic data in a Postgres database. There is one table in particular which is causing trouble. It is slowly approaching a billion rows and has three columns: `snp_name varchar(32), genotype_id int, local_genotype char(2)`

The first two are foreign keys and together form the primary key of the table.

Querying this data is still OK, response-time-wise. Inserting data takes ages, though. We are now at a point where we get new data faster than we can insert it, and we already `COPY` into a temporary table first and insert from there. Due to the server still running on spinning disks, inserting a genotype with a million rows takes about 5 hours.

Partitioning by `genotype_id` would be great, since this would result in ~ a thousand tables with a million rows each and a genotype is basically the package we get the data in. Then, querying by `snp_name` probably won't perform that well anymore, though. Whether we can live without it, has not yet been decided.

Do you have any suggestions for other options we could try? Are there any database systems, that allow indexing across partitions? Any NoSQL solutions that could fit?

**EDIT**: The table definition:

```
# \d user_snps
              Table "public.user_snps"
     Column     |         Type          | Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------+-----------
 snp_name       | character varying(32) |
 genotype_id    | integer               |
 local_genotype | character(2)          |
Indexes:
    "user_snps_new_genotype_id" btree (genotype_id)
    "user_snps_new_snp_name" btree (snp_name)
```

There is only one distinct value of `genotype_id` per insert, and all values of `snp_name` are unique per insert.

Comment: It's not actually the inserting that is taking time - that is just dumping rows into a heap. It must be something else, eg the FK lookups for the RI that have to happen too, or per-row triggers getting fired.

Comment: Have you tried to move the `varchar(32)` column out to a separate table and do joins when querying? I am wondering how much time the uniqueness check takes on inserts.  Anyway, 5 hours for inserting a million rows really suggests a trigger or similar, just like @JackDouglas said above.

Comment: I suppose what's taking so long is just updating the indexes, since there are no constraints or triggers on that table.

Comment: I would also help if you showed the definitions of the other 2 tables and a few sample rows. (the choice of a varchar(32) for a primary key does not seem optimal).

Comment: Updating the indexes may be generating a lot of IO - how many distinct values of `genotype_id` and of `snp_name` are there in a typical 1,000,000 row insert? Please reply with `@Jack` in your comment or I won't know you have...

Comment: @Jack I insert the rows all at once. There is only one distinct value of `genotype_id` per insert, and all `snp_name`s are unique per insert. `snp_name` also acts as a foreign key, so it could be replaced by an integer as well. We didn't do it, though, because then we would have to lookup `snps` before inserting into `user_snps`.

Comment: OK, that explains it. Presumably those `snp_name` values for one insert are distributed randomly/evenly throughout the index? In which case you are doing up to 1,000,000 writes which is going to slow you down. If you decide you can live without querying by `snp_name`, then just drop the `user_snps_new_snp_name` and you are done - don't muck about with partitioning, that will gain you nothing here.If you *can't* live without querying by `snp_name` then you will need to look at options for doing so another way.

Comment: For example you may be able to live with an index on the first n chars of `snp_name` - quicker to insert into and can give you a partial speed-up when querying. What kind of values does `snp_name` hold?

Answer (score -2):

I'm thinking having two copies of that table, one partitioned by `genotype_id`, one partitioned by `snp_name` and adding a few constraints and triggers to keep it consistent might be a good enough solution.

Comment: this will gain you nothing because if you partition by `snp_name` you are still going to take 5 hours to insert your 1,000,000 rows into that table.

Answer (score -2):

A different idea I had is to put the associations into array/hstore columns in the genotypes and snps tables.

Comment: this will open you up to a whole new world of pain